# Use alexnet and flow from directory to train grayscale dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

This is my reference:
[flow from directory example](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d)
[alexnet architecture](https://engmrk.com/alexnet-implementation-using-keras/)

I tried to train 3 categories using alexnet architecture. the dataset are grayscale images. I modified the first link to become a categorical class mode and then modified the CNN model to become alexnet from the second link.
I got 2 error messages:

1. ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv2d_83/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,1,384], [3,3,384,384].
2. If I change the img_width, img_height = 224,224
   TypeError: `Dense` can accept only 1 positional arguments ('units',), but you passed the following positional arguments: [4096, (224, 224, 1)]

Am I having an unmatched dimension in the CNN? 
thanks

Here is the code:

```
import json
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
#from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop


# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150,150

train_data_dir = 'data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data/validation'
nb_train_samples = 200*3
nb_validation_samples = 50*3
epochs = 1
batch_size = 5

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (1, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 1)
print(input_shape)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=input_shape,data_format='channels_last', kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(4,4), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# 4th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 5th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(1000))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

#model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001),metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    color_mode='grayscale',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    color_mode='grayscale',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model_in_json.json", "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(model_json, json_file)

model.save_weights("model_weights.h5")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `AlexNet` is meant to work with `input_size` of 227x227. The paper mentions 224x224, but it's a typo. It's not to say that you can't use other size, but the architecture will then make less sense then. More pronaunced problem appears when the input size is too small - i.e. your case. Convolutions with strides=2 and max pooling operations reduce dimensionality of subsequent layers. You simply run out of dimensions, which is indicated by `ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv2d_83/convolution'`. Upsample your input images or change the architecture.
2. The error stems from `model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape))`. If you check the `keras` docs for [Dense](https://keras.io/layers/core/) layer, you will notice that second argument is `activation`. If anything, you should use `model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=your_input_shape))`.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you very much for editing and also answering this query.